# classdefnotfoundexception while using a jar file inside a jar android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-library

I used gcm.jar in my project pushandroid . Now I want to make this pushandroid project into  library and use in other project gcmlib project. 
Push android project works well separately but when I use as a jar, it throws exception classdefnotfoundexception while calling gcmregistrar class methods. I have declared the services and recivers in both the manifest file of gcmlib project which uses jar inside jar and main project androidpush . Please let me know if I need to declare anything to use jar inside jar ?

Comment: You have to declare GCM register and GCM service classes only in the main package of the application. otherwise those classes will not work .

Comment: Yes, I have already declared GCM register and GCM service in the main package of the application too. Edited and mentioned the same in question now

Comment: You mentioned in GCM lib project..that way it will not work. you have to use them in your main project and with main package should be used in GCM declarations.

Comment: What IDE are using Eclipse or Android Studio please make sure that your gcm.jar is added to your pushandroid lib project and pushandroid lib project also added as library project to another project.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy now I have added in both projects. Main package is also used. But still getting the same error.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I am using eclipse. yes gcm.jar is used in both projects

Comment: It's important the fact that you have to import your project via "as library project", and the two projects (in this case, GCM and yours) should be in the same partition in your computer. This costs me several hours because it didn't give me compilation errors, but yes runtime ones.